# How do I create a star extrusion to circle?

Tags: mesh

Can anyone help me create a star extrusion to circle?

[image]

Comment: I had to see the answers to understand what this was asking. Perhaps "star extrusion to circle " should be reworded as "connect the star vertices to the circle".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take the star, go to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>).

Stay in edit mode and keep the selection. Choose "Transform: To Sphere" (<kbd>Shilft</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and drag the mouse until you have a nice circle. Scale the circle (<kbd>S</kbd>) if you think it's too big.

[image: Animation of the process]

Answer (score 17):

First of all, your **Circle** should have the same amount of vertices as your Star (or it can have more but then it will be more complicated).

Also you can add **Circle** in **Object Mode** and join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) it with Star or you can just add **Circle** while being in Star **Edit Mode**.

Then select both shapes (outer edges) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > **Bridge Edge Loops**.

After that you will want to select all and **Recalculate Normals** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm using ScreenToGif app: http://www.screentogif.com/

Answer (score 10):

Enable the Looptools Addon.

[image]

Extrude the star and then use the loop tools>circle to turn the selected vertices into a circle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want this as Node Setup and using Sverchok Add-On in Blender:

https://gist.github.com/2bbbe7e82730a625ec876948eaea6620

[image: node tree setup using sverchok to loft circle to star shape]

[image: star to circle extrusion]

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of adding more answers...

You can also do this backwards. Start with a cylinder, select one of the edge loops, do checker deselect and scale the selected vertices to form the star shape.

[image]