# How to model the wavy wrapper of a cupcake?

Tags: modeling

I'm sorry if the question in the title is incorrectly asked: I'm new to Blender and I'm practicing modeling.

I'm trying to make a cupcake, and I got stuck at the start - modeling the thing that cupcakes are in, in particular on how to model a wavy effect.

I don't know how to model that.

I hope I explained what I don't understand.

Comment: An image would be helpful to clarify what you are after. Something  [like this](http://hdydi.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/10295201346_995df07162_o-1.jpg) perhaps? What have you tried so far that hasn't worked for you?  Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/98953/edit)  to add this information.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90477/how-do-i-create-a-star-extrusion-to-circle/90667#90667

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's how I would model "the thing that cupcakes are in":

Start with a cylinder with an even number of vertices (like 40) and `NGon` cap fill:

[image: Cylinder]

## Give the cylinder the shape of a cupcake

Select the top face and make it larger by scaling it (<kbd>S</kbd>). Then, delete the face (<kbd>X</kbd>):

[image: After delete]

## Select half of the side edges

1. Switch to edge selecting mode
2. Select one edge at the top and one at the bottom circles
3. `Multi select loops` (Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for this function)
4. Select inverse (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)
5. Checker deselect (again, search for this)

[image: Selection]

## Create the waves

Make this selection larger by scaling it:

[image: Scale]

If you don't like the spikes, scale down in the z-direction (<kbd>S</kbd> to scale, and <kbd>Z</kbd> to use the `z` axis.

[image: Z scale]

## Fix the bottom

Go back to face selection mode and select the bottom face. Scale down over the z-axis to make the face flat. Then, poke it (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>). This will split the face into triangles, which is better for rendering.

[image: Poked]

## Make it look nicer

Exit edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Add the `Solidify` modifier. Adjust the thickness as desired. Add the `Bevel` modifier, with a very small width (like 0.02). Add the `Subdivision surface` modifier, to smooth it out. You can play with the settings a bit, and you should get something like this:

[image: Result]